# If user provided a color name or color number not supported by R change it to "yellow"

Tags: r, plot, colors

I have a function called `pick.col`. User of this function can provide **a color name** (e.g., `"purple"`, `"red"` etc.) or **a color number** (e.g., `2`, `17` etc.) as an argument.

## Question

Suppose a provides a color name or a color number that is not supported by R (e.g., "very light brown" or `-1e16`). In such cases, I want my function, to replace the user's erroneously picked color name or number with "yellow".

**But how can I have R check if user-provided *color number* or *color number* is supported by (i.e., exists in) R or not?**

```
pick.col = function(color) {

plot(1, pch = 19, cex = 8 , col = color)

}

pick.col(color = "yellow")
```

Comment: I know that `colors` in R lists all supported color names. Yet I don't know how to find supported color numbers.

Comment: `colors()` command can print all the colors for you

Comment: Color numbers are interpreted as indices of the current palette, which is returned by `palette()`. The default palette is numbers 1-8, corresponding to `"black", "red", "green3", "blue", "cyan", "magenta", "yellow", "gray"`. Personally, I would allow either number or name in the function, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would write a function which took either names *or* numbers as a parameter, returning an error if the supplied type was incorrect. However: here is how you could check for either. Note: I called the function *pick_col* not *pick.col*.

```
# function to check for whole numbers
is.wholenumber <- function(x, tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) {
  abs(x - round(x)) < tol
}

pick_col <- function(color = "yellow") {
  # if color is an integer
  if(is.numeric(color) && is.wholenumber(color)) {
      ifelse(color <= length(palette()), color, "yellow")
  }
  # if color is a string
  else if(is.character(color)) {
    ifelse(color %in% colors(), color, "yellow")
  }
  # anything else
  else {
    "yellow"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pick.col <- function(color) {
  color <- ifelse(color %in% colors(), color, "yellow")
  plot(1, pch = 19, cex = 8 , col = color)
}

pick.col(color = "ksjdhf")
```